# Git diff command in bash script returns nothing

Tags: bash, git, hook

I've created a pre-push git hook to manage my Jupyter notebooks in my repo (I want to suppress outputs from my notebooks but that's not the point of this post). At the beginning of my script I calculate in the `STAGED` variable all notebooks that have been modified since last commit (they all are in `notebooks` directory):

```
STAGED=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM --relative notebooks | grep .ipynb)
```

After modification of one of my notebooks, I `git add .` in terminal and make a `git diff` just to see if the notebook is in the git index. The `git diff` command returns as expected the modified file. I make a commit and a push. Pre-push hook is executed but I can see (with `echo $STAGED`) that the STAGED variable is empty. Just to be sure I also echo the current directory and it is, as expected, the root of my project (which contains `notebooks` directory with my notebooks). Why does the git diff command in bash script return nothing?

Comment: We can only guess, because you have not presented a [mre].  But perhaps because once you commit, the changes are no longer staged?

Comment: You're right John. When I git diff in terminal after git commit, the result is empty. Does it mean I should place my script in pre-commit hook instead of pre-push hook?

Comment: Once committed, you have to diff the trees of the commits, not your working directory against your index

Comment: I am in no way confident that I understand your intention for the script well enough to advise you on specifics.  However, `git diff --cached` reports on changes that have been staged but not yet committed, and a pre-push hook is almost certainly the wrong place for that.  A pre-commit hook seems a more sensible place.  Probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `git commit` whatever was on your stage becomes part of the commit, so `git diff --staged` will be empty.

If you want to see the changes from the previous commit to the current commit, then you have to do `git diff @~`, not `git diff --staged`.

Comment: Is it better to use `git diff --staged` in a pre-commit hook or `git diff @~` in a pre-push hook?

Comment: @Patrick That depends on what you want to do. The `pre-commit` hook will be executed at different times, and many more times. Also, if you want to stop the operation, the hook will stop a different operation.